How to show and hide button from page load by permission group How do it on Page Load by Code Behind
If a current logged user belongs to a given Sharepoint group, he or she should see button. If not belongs the button should hide. How could I do this from Page Load by code behind ? Please help me.
 if (SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Groups.Cast<SPGroup>().Any(g => g.Name == "hr Group"))
 {
    show button
 }
 else
 {
    hide button
 }


Which version of SharePoint? Are you using classic or modern experience site pages?

Also, you can use PNP SecurityTrimmedControl for your button show and hide in your SPFx. Please check details here: https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/SecurityTrimmedControl/
